# Accessing an object inside of an object is showing an empty result when attempting to log it

Tags: laravel, object

I am using Laravel 5.5, and I am performing a database selection:

```
Users::with("calendarMap")->where("id", $user->id)->get();
\Log::info($inviter);
```

And this is the result of the `Log`:

```
[  
  {  
    "id":12,
    "name":" ",
    "email":"sendfrombrazil@gmail.com",
    "first_name":null,
    "last_name":null,
    "status":"active",
    "is_activated":0,
    "created_at":"2018-02-06 06:57:48",
    "updated_at":"2018-02-06 06:57:48",
    "calendar_map":{  
      "member_id":7,
      "calendar_id":6,
      "user_id":12,
      "invited_by":10,
      "color":"#7D96E3",
      "role":"guest",
      "added_at":"2018-02-06 06:02:48"
    }
  }
]
```

But then, using `$inviter[0]->calendar_map->calendar_id` as I need fails by throwing an error saying `Trying to get property of non-object`.

If I then log out `$inviter[0]->calendar_map`, it will simply show NOTHING

> [2018-02-06 08:11:51] local.INFO:[3 blank spaces]

What pisses me off violently is that previously I have done something extremely similar, by querying with `with` another class, and I had done the **EXACT SAME THING** I showed, and worked. What is going on here?

Comment: `$inviter[0]->calendarMap->calendar_id` see what this gives

Comment: ... it works like this. Why the hell does it show `calendar_map` instead?

Comment: Thank you. I do not know if I would have figured out this.

Comment: This is typical Laravel naming conventions. Table names use snake_case, method names camelCase. Model mutators and accessors are perfect examples, if I wanted to customize `calendar_map` I would define `getCalendarMapAttribute` and `setCalendarMapAttribute`. Relationships between models follow this convention too. Something to keep in mind and and you sane.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't show, but the name of the method to assign the relationship is `calendarMap`. Although the object shows `calendar_map`, the correct way is:

> `$inviter[0]->calendarMap`